# chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension, but my [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) is not working.

My Manifest.jason

```
 {
    "name": "TypoSaurus",
    "version": "0",
    "description": "TypoSaurus extension",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "TypoSaurus",
        "icons": ["icon.png"],
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
            "js": ["jquery-2.0.2.min.js", "background.js"],
            "css": ["customStyles.css"],
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
        }],
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

and my background.js

```
function typo (tab) {

  alert('test');
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(typo);
```

The error that I am receiving is

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naming a script `background.js` does not magically make it a background script!

It's still defined as a content script in you manifest, and content scripts have [severely restricted access to Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). This causes the error you're experiencing.

Listeners for events like clicking the button should be done from one central location; this is the purpose of a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (on better, an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)). You should declare your script as such, and broadcast a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the content scripts if you need it.

All in all, please read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) carefully, it will help you a lot.

Comment: How should it help the one who faced the same problem? Did not suppose SO accepts docs redirection.

Comment: @FreeLightman I believe the text of my answer, without links, is sufficient to explain the gist of the problem. But if you disagree, you always have the downvote button and the ability to add your own, better answer.

Comment: the background page link doesn't work, and some of the links are outdated (manifest version 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can add script tag in your `background.html` file as below.

```
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

with this way you can use background script.

Issue with your current code

- `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` works only inside background script. 
   (content script don't have access to this)
- right now your `background.js` file is working as content script because you have mentioned that inside `content_scripts` array.